# Calculated column based on values from three other item columns

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a list where I want a 'Status' column to show different values based on entries from 3 other columns from the same list item.  These 3 columns are 2 choice columns 'Reviewed by' and 'Followed up by' both populated from a group and lastly 'Archived' which is a Yes/No choice.  I want the 'Status' to show 'Review' if there is a value in 'Reviewed by' column, but if there is a value in 'Followed up by' the 'Status' should be 'Follow up' and if the 'Archived' column is 'Yes' the 'Status' should then be 'Archived'.  When the item is created 'Status' would be set to 'New'as a default.  I've been thinking how to use the ISBLANK formula but can't figure out how to nest multiple IFs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To nest IF statements you just put them inside one another like so:

IF(test1, [FieldToShowIfTest1Suceeds], **IF(test2,[FieldToShowIfTest2Suceeds], [FieldToShowIfTest2Fails])** )

The 2nd IF in bold will be evaluated only if the first test fails.

So something like..

=IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Reviewed By])),[Reviewed By],IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Followed up by])),[Followed up by], [FieldToShowIfSecondIfFails]))

Comment: It works! Thankyou for your help Louis.